# Issue with passing list as argument to python function

Tags: python

```
def foo(val, arr=[]):
    arr.append(val)
    return arr

print(foo(1)) ---> outputs [1]
print(foo(2)) ---> outputs [1, 2]
```

Above happens because the default value (an empty list) was evaluated once, when the function was compiled, then re-used on every call to the function. If this is the case then I am not able to understand output of below python code

```
def f(x,l=[]):
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i*i)
    print(l) 

f(2)
f(3,[3,2,1])
f(3)
#This outputs below
[0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

Here in second call f(), list has been changed to `[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 4]` but in the third call to f() uses list created in first call f() i.e. `[0, 1]`

I am unable to understand how third call is not using list crated during 2nd f() call.

Comment: Obligatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First gotcha in the list http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

The list is only created once, so if you modify it then that modified version is used next time.

In the second call `f(3, [3,2,1])`; it isn't using the default list, it's using the one supplied by you.
So when you call a third time you're using the default list which was only modified by the first call.

as an example, looking up the memory addess for each object using [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

```
def foo(a=[]):
    print id(a)

foo()   #140378224732136
foo([]) #140378224687944
foo()   #140378224732136
```